# Rstudioでグループ別のglmを教えてください

Tags: r, tidyverse, rstudio

下記のデータフレーム（df）で
`glm(BP ~ age + sex + BMI, data = df)` を実施しています。
データフレームをそのままでグループ別（sex）に分析する方法はありますか？

**対象のデータフレーム:**

```
ID　age　sex　BP　BMI
1　　43　　0　120　21
2　　62　　1　130　26
3　　54　　1　132　23
4　　55　　0　110　19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dplyr を使う場合。

```r
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))

df <- data.frame(
    ID = 1:4, age = c(43, 62, 54, 55), sex = c(0, 1, 1, 0),
    BP = c(120, 130, 132, 110), BMI = c(21, 26, 23, 19)
)

result <- df %>% group_by(sex) %>% do(model = glm(BP ~ age + sex + BMI, data = .))

result$sex
result$model
```

> summary()を使用した結果もグループ別に見たい

`purrr` ライブラリの `map` を使う場合。

```r
library(purrr)

result$model %>% map(summary)
```

**追記**

> グループ別にモデルに出力は可能ですか

少し趣向が異なるかもしれませんが、`names()` でそれぞれに名前を付けることができます。

```r
names(result$model) = c("men", "women")
result$model$men
result$model$women
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。summary( )を使用した結果もグループ別に見たいのですが可能でしょうか？

Comment: 加えてグループ別にモデルに出力は可能ですか？
results_men <- df  %>%  group_by(sex ==0) %>% ...
results_women <- df  %>%  group_by(sex ==1) %>% ...
のようなイメージです

Comment: 「グループ別にモデルに出力は可能ですか？」 一応、リストにグループ別で入っています。`result$model[[which(result$sex == 0)]]` などとすれば、それぞれのグループの model を取り出せます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。見事に解決しました。

Comment: 参考までに追記してみました。

Comment: ありがとうございます！とても参考になります！